# did you run python setup.py develop?

Tags: python, ubuntu, error-handling, terminal

Hy Everyone,

I try to install a script on my server using a terminal but due the installation I get an error. I will past here, the last lines of terminal.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/paster", line 4, in 
 command.run()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 93, in run
 commands = get_commands()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 135, in get_commands
 plugins = pluginlib.resolve_plugins(plugins)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/pluginlib.py", line 82, in resolve_plugins
pkg_resources.require(plugin)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
 needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
 raise DistributionNotFound(req)
 pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: httpagentparser==1.7.8: Not Found for: r2 (did you run python setup.py develop?)
 oneprovider@dedi-fr-20388:~$
```

Can someone help me to fix it ? Should install python develop ? If yes, how ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message is quite clear: httpagentparser is not installed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpagentparser

You should install it first, maybe it's available in the ubuntu software center. Else install via pip:

```
pip install httpagentparser
```

And if you don't know pip and/or have pip not installed. See  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: I install httpagentparser, thanks. But the guideline of the script it say to not install anything because the automatic installer will do all.

Comment: If you install your script also via pip and the dependency packages are properly mentioned then yes, it should automaticly install httpagentparser

Comment: I restart the installation, I hope will work now. Thanks for help.

Comment: I also get an error because other module was not installed before this error, do you i can get other errors because I restart the installation ? I mean, I should make some clean before ?